# Making UIImageView rounded

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want my image to appear as a complete 360 degree circle. When I build and run my image appears as an oval.
[image]

```
@IBOutlet var profileImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
  profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
  profileImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor() .CGColor
  profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3

  picker.delegate = self
  picker.dataSource = self
  milesTextField.inputView = picker            
}
```

Comment: Your UIImageView is not a square. Check how do you create it. If you use Autolayout do not forget to check constraints also.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you use autolayout. And when you try to setup `cornerRadius` your frame's `width` isn't completely ready. In `viewDidLoad` method layout is not ready yet. You should put your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
  profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
  profileImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor() .CGColor
  profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3
}
```

Comment: it says i can't override viewDidLayoutSubview

Comment: The method name is viewDidLayoutSubview**s**, not viewDidLayoutSubview

Comment: @DanA, yeah, Duncan is right. My fault, I miss 's' at the end of method name.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you are using autolayout, you need to give 1:1 constraint to the imageview. Then the code you have is just fine.

Select the image and click on the pin in storybaord to add the constraints , and select **Aspect Ratio** constraint, by default it wil be having some ration like 3:4 or 4:3, you need to give it as **1:1**

**Note**: Do not keep any height/width constraint for the imageview.Just give the leading,trailing ,top,bottom and the 1:1 ratio constraint.

Comment: Select the image and click on the pin , and select Aspect Ratio constraints, by default it wil be having some ration like 3:4 or 4:3, you need to give it as 1:1

Comment: wait what is the pin?

Comment: you see the four buttons in the storyboard at the bottom, the third one from the left is called pin.

Comment: okay I didn't know thats what its called. Should I do constrain to margins?

Comment: Yeah. You should do to margins , and give the value 0 to all the four edges.Bottom constraint might not be needed. Just give leading trailing, top and the aspect ration constraint

Comment: where on thing do I give it 1:1 though i clicked aspect ratio but theres nothing there

Comment: after adding the aspect ration constraint, select the image view and on your right side on xcode, you will see a panel, with list of constraints added to the image view. Select the aspect ration constraint and click on edit, and choose 1:1 option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Identity inspector`, click the `Add button (+)` in the lower left of the user defined runtime attributes editor. Double click on the `Key Path` field of the new attribute to edit the key path for the attribute to `layer.cornerRadius` Set the type to `Number` and the value to `30`. To make a circular image from a square image, the radius is set to half the width of the image view. Or you can add this code, I find the first way easier but you can decide which one to use.

```
// 30 is an example you can do the math and divide the width of the image
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0 
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If your UIImageView not a square, may be impossible to used UIImageView.layer.cornerRadius to make UIImageView to Circle.

**Alternative** 
May be make your image to circle, then add it to UIImageView.

**Here code create Circle image before add it to UIImageView.**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!
    let imgTest = UIImage(named: "Lion.jpg")!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imgView.image = circleImage(imgTest)
    }

    func circleImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, 1.0)

        let q = min(image.size.width, image.size.height)
        let bp = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: image.size.width/2, y: image.size.height/2), radius: q/2, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI) * 2, clockwise: true)
        bp.addClip()
        image.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))

        let imgLast = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imgLast
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an option to round each `UIImageView`, you can copy this code into your project without forgetting to check `clip to bounds` and set its value to `true`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
extension UIImageView
{
    private struct AssociatedKey
    {
        static var rounded = "UIImageView.rounded"
    }

    @IBInspectable var rounded: Bool
    {
        get
        {
            if let rounded = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.rounded) as? Bool
            {
                return rounded
            }
            else
            {
                return false
            }
        }
        set
        {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.rounded, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(newValue ? 1.0 : 0.0)*min(bounds.width, bounds.height)/2
        }
    }
}
```

[image: storyboard screenshot]